# Proper use of '/opt' folder on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, file-permissions

Linux System: `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

I copy some app (like `xxx`) to the `/opt` folder to be used also by another user-accounts. Then to start it I use:

> sudo /opt/xxx_folder/xxx

(of course, links to /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin, etc.) to start it;

**Problem:** I'm storing the results/projects of the app to my local folder ( like `/home/myuser/xxx_data`). And of course the folder and it's data `xxx_data` belongs to `root` (not `myuser`). So I have to change the owner every time I want to edit those files using another app not as a root.

**Question:** is there a way to install an app `xxx` to `/opt` so, that I don't need to start them as a root?

**OR** maybe you see another way to solve this 'root-user-problem?'

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: That's true, I'll try Unix & Linux Stack Exchange also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add execute permission to any file like this.

```
sudo chmod +x file.sh
```

If you want to do that for all files in that folder try this:

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/*
```

Note the `+x` just adds execute permission to your logged in user. I think all users have read (`+r`) by default so if you also want to add write permission:

```
sudo chmod +xw /opt/*
```

Personally I keep all my custom scripts in a bin folder e.g. `/opt/bin/` and just do:

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/bin/*
```

To run the script without the full path add the bin or full opt folder to your path by adding the following to `~/bashrc` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin
```

If you don't end up using the `bin` folder, edit above to be `/opt` instead of `/opt/bin`.